# Select menu not changing .css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<div id="theme">
            <span>Theme:</span>
                <select onchange="getval(this);">
                    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                    <option value="red">Red</option>
                </select>
</div>
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

JavaScript:

```
function getval(sel) {

          var x = sel.value;

          if(x = 'red')
          {
            alert('i am red');
            $('h1').css('border-bottom-color', 'red');
          }

          if(x = 'blue')
          {
            alert('i am blue');
            $('h1').css('border-bottom-color', '#1d6094');
          }
}
```

CSS:

```
h1{
    border-bottom: 5px solid #1d6094;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: auto;
    line-height: 100%;
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pf6Pt/

I don't understand why the h1 css isn't changing when I change the color from red to blue in the drop down menu. Perhaps a case statement would solve my issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x = 'red'` assigns `'red'` to `x` (same thing with blue). You want to compare `x` to `'red'` (or `'blue'`).

```
if(x == 'red') {
    alert('i am red');
    $('h1').css('border-bottom-color', 'red');
}

if(x == 'blue') {
    alert('i am blue');
    $('h1').css('border-bottom-color', '#1d6094');
}
```

Another way to bind the event listener (which worked in fiddle):

```
var select = document.getElementById('my-select-element');
select.onchange = function() {
  setval(select);
};
```

I forgot you are using jQuery. That makes everything a lot simpler. Look at [yuvi's example](http://jsfiddle.net/zmHJQ/).

Comment: have to wait 5 mins :P

Comment: I just want to point out, that inside jsfiddle, this isn't enough because adding onchange attribute to the select causes a 'not defined' error (it seems the js is run after the html). So you have to bind it inside the js, see [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/zmHJQ/). This point is only relevant to jsfiddle, but is worth noting I think

Answer (score 0):

```
   if(x === 'red')
```

or

```
   if(x == 'red')
```

and not

```
if(x = 'red')
```

**Note :**  `===` is better than `==` because it is a strict equivalence

Comment: `===` is not better in this situation.